# How to sort array by date but missing out the first array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object

I want to sort an array by date. But ignore the first item in the array. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have this currently:

```
articles.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(b.published) - new Date(a.published);
});
```

my array looks like this:

```
[
    {id: 1, published: Mar 12 2012 08:00:00 AM}, 
    {id: 2, published: Mar 9 2012 08:00:00 AM},
    {id: 3, published: Mar 15 2012 08:00:00 AM},
    {id: 4, published: Mar 22 2012 08:00:00 AM},
    {id: 5, published: Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM}
];
```

I just need to sort everything by date from id 2 - 5

What I have sorts everything.

Thanks

Comment: Your function relies on a `published` property that doesn't exist in the array you provided. Please update your post as necessary.

Comment: Yes thank I've amended that.

Comment: you want to ignore the first element in the array after sorting or before sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `shift()` to remove the first element and `unshift()` to put it back at the first position:

```
var first = articles.shift();
articles.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(b.published) - new Date(a.published);
});
articles.unshift(first);
```

Answer (score 1):

Then, you can shift the first row, and readd after sorting.

```js
var articles = [
    {id: 1, published: "2018-01-09"}, 
    {id: 2, published: "2019-01-01"},
    {id: 3, published: "2019-01-04"},
    {id: 4, published: "2019-01-03"},
    {id: 5, published: "2019-01-02"}
];
var first = articles.shift();
articles.sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(b.published) - new Date(a.published);
});
articles.unshift(first);
console.log(articles);
```

Comment: You've beat me to it. I am typing to slow =)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply exclude the `id:1` from your [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by returning `1` if the `id` matches `1`:

```js
let dates = [ {id: 1, published: 'Mar 12 2012 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 2, published: 'Mar 9 2012 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 3, published: 'Mar 15 2012 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 4, published: 'Mar 22 2012 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 5, published: 'Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM'} ];

let result = dates.sort((a,b) => 
   a.id == 1 || b.id == 1 ? 1 : new Date(a.published) - new Date(b.published))

console.log(result)
```

This way you would not need to `concat`, `slice` or `shift` anything.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the first item in the array, `sort` on the `slice`d array, and then merge with the first item. Also note that the timestamp needs to be a string - currently its invalid.

```js
const articles = [{id:1,published:"Mar 12 2012 08:00:0 AM"},{id:2,published:"Mar 9 2012 08:00:0 AM"},{id:3,published:"Mar 15 2012 08:00:0 AM"},{id:4,published:"Mar 22 2012 08:00:0 AM"},{id:5,published:"Mar 8 2012 08:00:0 AM"}];
const res = [].concat(articles[0], articles.slice(1).sort(({ published: a }, { published: b }) => new Date(a) - new Date(b)));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```